# Django model manager isn't working as expected

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model "Name" in models.py file of a django app.

```
from .managers.py import NameManager
class Name(models.Model):
    .......................
    objects = NameManager()
```

I have created NameManager in managers.py file.

```
class NameManager(models.Manager):

    def get_func(self, arg):
        ..............
        

    def check_func(self, arg1, arg2):
        ..............
```

Now in my views.py file, when I write:

```
from .models import Name
if Name.check_func(arg1, arg2):
    .........................
```

I am getting an error:

> type object 'Name' has no attribute 'check_func'

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API for custom managers - but shouldn't this be `Name.objects.check_func(arg1, arg2)`?

Comment: Yes, it should. That was the mistake, a silly one. I am getting another error now but maybe it is related to my implementation.
Thanks.